# How restrict users to access only system table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise

We have a usecase where we create a user and provide CREATE, ALTER, SELECT, MODIFY and AUTHORIZE permissions on all the keyspaces because they can create keyspace and drop them if needed. However we want to restrict the users to do any changes to system keyspace.

```
LIST ALL PERMISSIONS OF test;

 role | username | resource        | permission
------+----------+-----------------+------------
 test |     test | <all keyspaces> |     CREATE
 test |     test | <all keyspaces> |      ALTER
 test |     test | <all keyspaces> |     SELECT
 test |     test | <all keyspaces> |     MODIFY
 test |     test | <all keyspaces> |  AUTHORIZE
```

I tried to revoke it after granting it on all keyspaces but it is not working.

```
REVOKE SELECT on keyspace system from test;
```

is there a way to achieve this without granting access to each keyspace?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict certain tables in the system keyspace. They are required for any driver functionality so they cannot be blocked. If you have a valid user login they must be open and Cassandra will automatically grant all users permission to access them even if you alter roles.

---

Source code for this:

See [building the list of always readable tables](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/c1fa21458777b51a9b21795330ed6f298103b436/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/ClientState.java#L63-L85)

```
// We want these system cfs to be always readable to authenticated users since many tools rely on them
// (nodetool, cqlsh, bulkloader, etc.)
for (String cf : Arrays.asList(SystemKeyspace.LOCAL, SystemKeyspace.PEERS))
    READABLE_SYSTEM_RESOURCES.add(DataResource.table(SystemKeyspace.NAME, cf));

SchemaKeyspace.ALL.forEach(table -> READABLE_SYSTEM_RESOURCES.add(DataResource.table(SchemaKeyspace.NAME, table)));
```

This code builds up the `READABLE_SYSTEM_RESOURCES` which are always readable to any authenticated user.

See [hasAccess returning (passing) if trying to select from those tables](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/c1fa21458777b51a9b21795330ed6f298103b436/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/ClientState.java#L311-L312)

```
if ((perm == Permission.SELECT) && READABLE_SYSTEM_RESOURCES.contains(resource))
    return;
```

---

Docs describing this
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureObjectPerms.html